# Set specific file types to hidden using BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am currently trying to set all `.txt` file types within the test folder to hidden. I have tried running the batch with no luck. What am I missing?

```
@ECHO OFF
for "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\test" %%a IN (*.txt) DO attrib +h "%%a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attrib +h "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\test\*.txt"
```

should be easier, but you don't tell us what happened.

Comment: This is for a homework assignment but we  were poorly informed on how to do it.  We were only told to hide the txt files using the "For" command within a batch file.  Even running this command in cmd with the directory of the files does not make them hidden.

Comment: Ok it seems Windows 8 defaults to "Show hidden files folders, and drives".  Would that be my issue?

Comment: @RyanMcCloy - Hidden files will appear greyed out when the Show Hidden Files option is set. You can right-click on them and select properties and see if the Hidden box is checked.

Comment: Ah - homework.... use an inapproriate method to do something. No need for the `for` - but it's a requirement. Try executing a `DIR *.txt` before your `for` and then after. You'll se that before you see the files, after you don't **but** using `dir /a:h *.txt` will give you a different story...

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information!  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The source path goes inside the parentheses.

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%a IN (C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\test\*.txt) DO attrib +h "%%a"
```

Comment: I tried this and the files in the source path "test" are still not hidden.  I run the batch and nothing happens.  Windows 8.1 64bit if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for %%x in ("\path\to\directory\*.txt") do @attrib +h "%%x"
```